# a * a//b doesn't work properly in Python (// Operator)

Tags: python, operator-keyword, division

The python / / operator is integer division.

But in case of a * a//b, It works like a * a/b..

```
a = 10
b = 3
a * a//b
>> 33

a//b * a
>> 30

temp = a//b
a * temp
>> 30
```

Why is this happening??

Comment: `a * a//b = 10 * 10//3 = 100//3 = 33`. What is wrong with this ?

Comment: `100 // 3` is different from `3 * 10`, yes.

Comment: Python doesn't care about space *that* much.

Comment: oh my god im sorry.. TT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably meant to write `a * (a//b)`. Multiplication happens before division, since it's on the left and has same priority.

Answer (score 0):

The order of operations is the same in both cases, but there is an implicit integer truncation operation happening in different parts of the two statements.

In the first case, you truncate to an integer at the end, in the second case, you do that at the start. As a result, you get different answers.

Comment: What do you mean with "The order of operations is the same in both cases"?